# 3D Building automatic texture software recommendations?

Tags: 3d, modeling, gis, digital-asset-management

Does anyone have any recommendations for any software (proprietary/opensource/programmable) that can automatically texture 3D building models (collada/shp) from digital aerial camera (large/medium format) frames?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/327034/115